# Is it possible to have an image be picture-in-picture and just tell FCPX to keep it at its original size?

Tags: final-cut-pro-x

By default, when I drop an image into the timeline, it fills the full width of the video. Which I don't want. Is it possible to say, "adjust yourself to your actual size"? And if so, how?

Answer (score 2):

By "actual size" I suppose you want to conform your footage *pixel to pixel* instead of *frame to frame*. For this you will need to change *Spatial Conform* to *None* in the inspector.

The new default behavior in FCP is to scale your footage to either "fit" or "fill" the project's frame, the difference being only relevant when your footage doesn't have the same aspect as the project's. This conforming defines the actual 100% Scale in the Transform panel. So make sure the scale is also set to 100%.

You can find more information about Spatial Conform in it's [documentation](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH12648).

Comment: Welcome to Video Production on Stack Exchange.  Thanks for stepping up and answering this question.  If possible to add a few more details summarizing what Spatial Conform is, this would be an even more helpful answer.  I doubt the Apple link will go dead anytime soon, but it's nice to have a little detail in the answer so that the link is mostly just further reference.

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome and the up vote AJ. I added some more explanation.